# Store optional bool in NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store an optional `bool` in `NSUserDefaults` where all three states are meaningful.

- `nil` -> Hasn't been set yet
- `true`/`false` -> Has explicitly been set to this value

At the moment, it seems that if you retrieve a `bool` from the `NSUserDefaults`, if it has not been set then it returns `false`, which won't work for the above mentioned use case.

I don't want to user an `enum` as it seems overkill for what I am looking to achieve.

Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: If all three states are really meaningful perhaps Bool isn’t the correct value type to use?

Comment: Don't store anything to represent nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just take value from UserDefaults and try to cast it to `Bool`. If there is no value for key u get nil.

`let myBool = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "BoolKey") as? Bool`

or

`let myBool = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "BoolKey") as? Bool`

`myBool = nil` in both cases

thanks `user28434` for addition

Comment: *`object(forKey:)`. `value(forKey:)` is unrelated function from [completely different domain](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i).

Comment: In fact you're right but for UserDefaults `object(forKey:)` works under the hood as `value(forKey:)`

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't. `value(forKey:)` maybe is calling `object(forKey:)` for `UserDefaults`. But not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

`Bool` – as well as `Int` and `Double` – in `UserDefaults` is treated as non-optional, all dedicated getters return `0/false` if the key does not exist.

A workaround is either to check first for `nil` with `object(forKey` or to save a string and implement a computed property to map the types.

In practice is *not set* and *false* really a difference?

Comment: "In practice is not set and false really a difference?" Yes. Imagine the question "do you want fries with that?" There's a difference between the answer "no" and not having been asked the question yet.

Comment: Upvoted because your idea of testing for the presence of the key is the right way to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
if !UserDefaults.standard.valueExists(forKey: "yourKey") {
                // do something
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "yourKey")
            } else {
    // do something else
 }

extension UserDefaults {
func valueExists(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
    object(forKey: key) != nil
}
}
```